# How does AWS CDK "know" which constructs have been created inside a class

Tags: aws-cdk

I am seeing AWS example CDK code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/hello_world.html that looks like this

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { aws_s3 as s3 } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

export class HelloCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyFirstBucket', {
      versioned: true
    });
  }
}
```

And CDK synthesis tool somehow knows that this code creates a S3 bucket in the HelloCDK stack. Coming from Java, I have not seen this "Get all classes instantiated with a classes constructor and do something with them", especially because this code

```
    new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyFirstBucket', {
      versioned: true
    });
```

Reads to me as a class instance with no pointer, and thus something that would get garbage collected.

How is AWS CDK using this info? Is this a pattern specific to typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you create a construct in the CDK you have to provide it a scope as the first parameter. In your example, you have provided 'this' as the scope of the bucket. 'this', the stack, becomes the parent of the bucket in a tree the constructs maintain. This is the only internal pointer you have and need to any constructs that get created. Because there is this one reference then there's no garbage to clean up.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how does the ```cdk synth``` command know how to find the root of this tree?

Comment: `cdk synth` runs the 'app', which is defined in the cdk.json file. (or you can override it) and that's usually just a basic node module being loaded. For example, I use project so my app is `npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts src/main.ts`. `main.ts` creates a new app, creates stacks with that app as the 'scope' and then calls app.synth(), so it's the app.synth that knows how to traverse the tree and render all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing too much about the details but there is a pointer in the arguments. The first argument attaches the construct to the CDK tree internally build cdk.out/tree.json .

Perhaps a bit like recursion. You can do recursion in Java.